# Shell script date arithmetics

Tags: perl, shell, ksh

Here's my high level problem.

I want to read a number `max_age_in_secs` from a config file. This number represents the number of seconds we consider a file is "old". After we read this config, we want to search all files in a directory `data` and delete all files modified before `max_age_in_secs` seconds ago.

This has to be done as a shell script, more specifically korn shell.

What I'm doing right now is to touch a dummy file to be modified `max_age_in_secs` ago, then use `find` and its `! -newer` option to search for files older than that.

I'm having a problem getting a timestamp to pass to `touch`. The `date` command on my unix box doesn't have the option `--date` so I can't use that.

I'm looking at `perl -e "blah_blah_blah"` but I need to pass the `max_age_in_secs` variable to the perl command. The only way I know to do that is creating a new `.pl` file and pass arguments to that file. But ideally I would like to have this functionality in one korn script file. A workaround may be constructing a `perl_command` variable, and execute its content, but I think that's not secure and vulnerable to injections.

But I'm relatively new to shell scripting and perl, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to pass an environment variable from a shell to a one-line perl command:

- Directly. Most shells (including korn) interpolate expressions inside double quotes.

```
perl -e "print $VAR"
```

so in this case `$VAR` is coming from the shell. This technique has a lot of shortcomings, namely that with an `-e "double quoted expression" it is a pain to use other Perl variables or use a lot of other useful Perl constructions that might be misconstrued by the shell.

- As a command line argument, accessed in the perl script in `@ARGV`

```
perl -e 'print "VAR is $ARGV[0]"' $VAR
```

This will do if you don't need to use `@ARGV` (which are implicitly used if you use the `-p` or `-n` switches, or if your program uses the default `<>` operator).

- Through Perl's `%ENV` hash.

```
perl -e 'print "VAR is $ENV{VAR}"'
```

This mechanism doesn't interfere with `@ARGV`

Comment: If you use `%ENV`, make sure you `export` the shell variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e '... $ENV{max_age_in_secs}...'
```

as long as you do

```
export max_age_in_secs
```

in bash/sh/ksh

Answer (score 0):

Instead of seconds use minutes. Recent versions of `find` have the `mmin` option. For example, the following commands delete files older than a minute.

```
find /path/ -type f -mmin +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: if the date command on the server doesn't have --date, I assume the find command won't  have -mmin...

Comment: @Jean, you're exactly right. I tried -mmin with no luck. Thanks dogban for your suggestion.